# Сохранить изображение в одноканальном режиме

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

Пытаюсь сохранить изображение в оттенках серого в одноканальном режиме, но вместе этого сохраняется в трехканальном режиме. То есть просто копирует информацию в остальные каналы.

```
img1_dir = r'2.jpg'
load_img1 = cv2.imread(img1_dir)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(load_img1, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
image_array = np.expand_dims(gray, -1)
cv2.imwrite(r'1.png', image_array)
```

Как сохранить в одноканальном режиме?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[В документации указано, что по умолчанию `cv2.imread(filename, flags=IMREAD_COLOR)`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/imgcodecs/doc/reading_and_writing_images.html#Mat%20imread(const%20String&%20filename,%20int%20flags)) использует флаг `IMREAD_COLOR` (пытается прочитать изображение в цвете (3 канала: **BGR** - **B**lue, **G**reen, **R**ed))Ж

> **flags:**

```
>0 Return a 3-channel color image.
=0 Return a grayscale image.
<0 Return the loaded image as is (with alpha channel).
```

Т.е. для любого значения параметра `flags` больше нуля изображение будет читаться как 3-х канальное.

```
In [53]: print(cv2.IMREAD_COLOR )
1

In [54]: print(cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
0
```

Таким образом можно сразу читать изображение в оттенках серого:

```
gray = cv2.imread(img1_dir, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
```

или

```
gray = cv2.imread(img1_dir, 0)
```

и нет никакой необходимости конвертировать или сохранять его в оттенках серого.

При чтении изображения в режиме оттенков серого - матрица `gray` будет двумерной:

```
In [38]: gray.shape
Out[38]: (2272, 1704)

In [39]: type(gray)
Out[39]: numpy.ndarray
```

Comment: мне нужно именно сохранить, для дальнейшего использования.

Comment: @Sonfire, я думал это очевидно... ;-) Добавил в ответ

Comment: Это не то. Если потом считывать средствами на OpenCV, то опять получается трех канальное изображение

Comment: @Sonfire, [просто правильно читайте файл](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18870603/in-opencv-python-why-am-i-getting-3-channel-images-from-a-grayscale-image) и будет вам счастье